# In QGIS, can the 'spatialite execute sql' algorithm accept '.sql' text files?

Tags: qgis, sql, qgis-modeler, spatialite

I'm working in Model Designer on a process which includes running an SQL on a SpatiaLite database. I have the connection as the input, but I want the SQL to come from a text file 'xxxx.sql'. Intuitively, I used the input 'File/Folder' as the other model input, but weirdly, it seems from the error report to take the file *name*, from that input, not the file *contents*, which is odd.

I get

```
Error encountered while running SpatiaLite execute SQL (registered DB): Error executing SQL:
Error executing SQL {filepath}.sql: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2({filepath}.sql):
near "/": syntax error
```

The 'near "/"' part seems to imply it's used the actual file path of the file (there's no "/" in my SQL, needless to say).

Firstly, is there a way of extracting the text (the actual SQL) from the file to use as the SQL in the algorithm?

Secondly, is this a bug? I can't think of a single case where someone would want to use the file *name* as an input by default, but not the file *contents*, so I'm thinking possibly it's an error?

Comment: Ogr2ogr is using @filename syntax https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html but probably it is off-topic.